# How to convert yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to "15th Apr 2010" using PHP

Tags: php, date, format

I have the following date format: **2010-04-15 23:59:59**

How would I go about converting this into: **15th Apr 2010**

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
echo date("jS M Y",strtotime("2010-04-15 23:59:59"));
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to using `date` and `strtotime`, you can do

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2010-04-15 23:59:59');
echo $dateTime->format('jS M Y'); // 15th Apr 2010
```

or

```
$dateTime = date_create('2010-04-15 23:59:59');
echo date_format($dateTime, 'jS M Y'); // 15th Apr 2010
```

Comment: And thank you for your help Gordon, I see there are quite a few ways to play around with the solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
$date = date("dS M Y",strtotime("2010-04-15 23:59:59"));

print $date;
```

Comment: "d" is day of month with leading zero, i think in this case "j"(day of month without leading zero) would be the better solution.