# How to convert YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss?

Tags: php, date, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to “15th Apr 2010” using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629392/how-to-convert-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-to-15th-apr-2010-using-php)

I have connected to a bank that it gives me a report in YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss format , but i need this format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss to store in db , what can i do in php now?

Comment: What bank represents dates as YYYY-DD-MM?  I've never seen that particular format before -- and since it's ambiguous with ISO 8601 format, it strikes me as a *very* bad idea.

Comment: libertyreserve.com , how can report to iso 8601

Comment: I have no idea how to get the bank to give you YYYY-MM-DD.  You might consider contacting them.  Converting from YYYY-DD-MM to YYYY-MM-DD is easy enough, but you can't reliably tell which one you have in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use the DateTime class:

```
<?php
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:i:s', $yourDateString);

if (! $date) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf("'%s' is not a valid date.", $yourDateString));
}

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: Note that the format values should be: 'Y-d-m H:i:s' and 'Y-m-d H:i:s' accordingly here

Comment: it returnes an error : Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\headortailcasino.com\test.php on line 5

Comment: thats because either the format is wrong, or the input was wrong and the object wasnt created... DateTime::createFromFormat returns a DateTime object on success or false on failure

Comment: Probably DateTime extension isn't installed/enabled. Also your date format is way off, check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Answer (score -2):

```
 <?php
     $date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
     $query = "INSERT into table_name ('date') VALUES ('$date')";
     $result = mysql_query($query);
 ?>
```

In your database, make sure you need to set the type of the date in that format, try TIMESTAMP

Comment: Among other things, that is not a valid date format for PHP. [Check it out for yourself](http://codepad.org/NAEHzlsR), it's hilarious: `2012201220122012-MonMon-MarMar 1111:0303:5959` The other answer made the same mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I know because the Y alone means the whole year, php.net/date, what I'm trying to do is I just connected with the question, the person who ask the question just emphasize the YYYY-DD and so on Mr. Know it All.

Comment: also I already edit it FOR YOU Mr. Know It All, and oh, also thanks for saying it's hilarious, I know your veteran here, but maybe I also know that's not the right way on giving advice Mr. Know It All, maybe you should change your name Madmartigan to Mr. Know It All, picking on some noobs yeah?

Comment: I meant no harm Mr. SuperNoob. Don't you think the output is funny? Also, why are you doing a database insert just to convert a date? It doesn't make sense. That's why I downvoted, nothing personal - we're all here to learn.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry Mr. MadMartigan, Maybe I should put the question here eh? "I have connected to a bank that it gives me a report in YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss format , but i need this format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss to store in db , what can i do in php now?"

also why I am doing a database insert just to convert a date? What?!

Comment: Ah you're right, he's putting in the database. My mistake. However, this doesn't convert the date from the bank report into the specified format, as requested. This uses the *current* date...

Comment: Yes Sir, actually I know its the current date, I converted the current date to that format because I think I can use it for my example, What do you think Sir? also we can do that if he put the data from the bank on the variable, I think he know how to write a code because he's asking how to insert the data (converted) in the db, and also I think you should create your own example if you have a better example than me (Of Course)

Comment: Your date format is still not right, but maybe we interpreted the question differently. I'm pretty sure it should be `Y-m-d H:m:s` and not `Y-D-M h:m:s`. `h` is only the 12 hours date format, so you'd need am/pm, and `D-M` makes `Tue-Mar`. See for yourself: http://codepad.org/wT9PDUDw I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm sorry, I'll just edit it. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Yet another way: You can use a regular expression replace:

```
$out = preg_replace("/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/", "$1-$3-$2", $in);
```

Comment: I didn't -1 because it works. Although he could do this, doesn't mean he should.

Comment: The down votes are probably because your code does not in anyway validate the dates. In contrast the other answer only works with valid dates and is more readable (since it explicitly shows before and after format)

Comment: this code works great , I've voted +1

Comment: @Guvante: the author didnt say anything about validation ;) on the contrary, if the input is flawed, the DateTime example will be crippled while this one will just rewrite the string...

Comment: @AMINGholibeigian: The example with DateTime will work too, if you change the format values to ones PHP uses (see [link](http://php.net/date) )